# Electrolysis with sodium acetate solution - pH stratified layers - what happened?

Tags: electrolysis

I electrolyzed 0.5M CH₃COONa in an H-Cell with a pH-sensitive dye using platinum electrodes. From the attached pic, you can see that an acidic layer formed at the top of the anode solution, while an alkaline layer formed at the bottom of the cathode solution. I understand why there is an acid and a base, but I don't understand why they stratified into these layers. What happened?

[image]

Comment: You should at least try to analyze the situation. what is being formed, where, how it could affect density and if there are any convective processes.

Comment: @Poutnik ok, there is the upwards convective process from the gas bubbles forming on both electrodes, which might explain the acidity at the top of the anode chamber (I also see the alkaline solution temporarily rise by the cathode). I was expecting the only products to be H2 and O2, and to see localized pH changes while the electrolysis was running. What I don't understand is why the alkaline solution sunk. I feel it must be due to density, but am unsure what would form that is more dense.

Comment: I also get that water with NaOH is more dense, but I'm not sure why it would not have mixed with the rest of the solution. The experiment has been sitting there 1 day now (without current applied), and while the acidic layer is gone, I still have a nice stratified alkaline layer.